# Using React.js statics inside class methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following widget class:

```
var Widget = React.createClass({
    statics: {title: "a title"},
    ...
});
```

Is there a way of accessing the title static inside the class'es methods (using `this`)? For example:

```
render: function() {
    return <div>{this.title}</div>;
}
```

Comment: you cannot access statics within the class. You can only do Widget.title

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can access a static from within the component from `this.constructor`:

so in this case it would be:

```
this.constructor.title
```

Comment: Is this documented? If so could we get the link?

Answer (score 8):

The direct answer:

```
React.createClass({
    title: 'a title',
    render: function() {
        return <div>{this.title}</div>;
    }
});
```

Or:

```
React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function(){
        this.title = 'a title';
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>{this.title}</div>;
    }
});
```

But really... why not just use a variable?

```
var TITLE = 'a title';

React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>{TITLE}</div>;
    }
});
```

Comment: Be warned, in example #3 `TITLE` will be static and shared among every instance of the class.

Comment: Yes, I believe that was the intention here because the OP mentioned statics.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question. My preferred style is your example #3 by a long shot.

Answer (score 7):

The `statics` object of a React Class is a way to define static methods (i.e., methods that don't need any context to run). That being said, it doesn't make sense to call a static method from `this`.

It looks like you're looking for a "static" property (i.e., non-mutable). So, you should use it like `this.props.title` on `render()`. To set the value of title, you should do `<Widget title='a title'/>`. It worths mentioning that you can set default properties, by defining the [`getDefaultProps`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values) method.

More about [statics](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#statics) and about [props](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#component-properties) on React's doc.